# Switch "Google page" off on Android

Tags: google-now, home-screen

I got Huawei P30 lite with Android 9. There is a page on the main screen (if you swipe right from Home) which looks like combination of Google assistant, search, news, weather etc..

What is it called and how to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the instruction from Huaweihub on how to disable Google Feed on the P30 Lite

1. Hold your finger on an area of blank space on the Homescreen.
2. Select Homescreen Settings.
3. Locate Google Feed, then swipe the adjacent toggle from On to Off.

Original article here: [How to disable Google Feed on the Huawei P30](http://huaweihub.com/explainer/how-to-disable-google-feed-huawei-p30-pro/)

Comment: Thanks! This works on an LG GPad 5 as well :)